# Take post data and translate that text into some paragraphs explaining the individual requests

Tags: php, forms, post, checkbox, isset

I have been successful at posting the answers to some questions. Now i want to take those answers and translate them to some text further explaining their options. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I feel like im stumped, this is my first attempt at php. any help would be amazing.

Here is my first page:

```
       <body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="title"><h1>Mortgages</h1></div>
  <div class="content">
  <form name="myform" action="process.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="check_submit" value="1" />
    Name: <input type="text" name="Name" />
    <br /><br />

    How soon are you interested in purchasing your new home <br />
      <input type="radio" name="timeFrame" value="90_days" /> 90- Days
      <input type="radio" name="timeFrame" value="1_Year" /> 1 Year
      <input type="radio" name="timeFrame" value="Just_Shopping" /> Just Shopping
    <br /><br /><br />
    Are you interested in getting more information on any of the following: <Br />
      <input type="checkbox" name="Programs[]" value="FHA" checked="checked" /> FHA
      <input type="checkbox" name="Programs[]" value="Conventional" /> Conventional
      <input type="checkbox" name="Programs[]" value="VA" /> VA
      <input type="checkbox" name="Programs[]" value="HELOC" /> HELOC
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" />
  </form>

  </div>


  </div>
</body>
```

Her is my PHP

```
       <?php
//Check whether the form has been submitted
if (array_key_exists('check_submit', $_POST)) { 
   //Check whether a $_GET['Languages'] is set
   if ( isset($_POST['Programs']) ) { 
     $_POST['Programs'] = implode(', ', $_POST['Programs']); //Converts an array into a single string
   }

   echo "Your name: {$_POST['Name']}<br />";
   echo "How soon are you interested in purchasing your new home: {$_POST['timeFrame']}<br />";
   echo "You interested in getting more information on any of the following: {$_POST['Programs']}<br />";
} else {
    echo "You can't see this page without submitting the form.";
}
?>
```

:--------------------------------------------------------Take two
Okay now I have my data being written to in a database using the following code:

```
<?php
define('DB_NAME', 'butler_site');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    $db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die('can\'t use' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
    }
$value = $_POST['name'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO mortgage (name) VALUES ('$value')";

if (!mysql_query ($sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
$value = $_POST['email'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO mortgage (email) VALUES ('$value')";

if (!mysql_query ($sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
$value = $_POST['timeFrame'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO mortgage (timeframe) VALUES ('$value')";

if (!mysql_query ($sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
$value = $_POST['programs'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO mortgage (programs) VALUES ('$value')";

if (!mysql_query ($sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }


mysql_close();
?>
```

What function should I use to take the data and attach it to some data that will explain the program further?

Comment: The title of your post should reflect the problem

Comment: the text of the post should reflect the problem

Comment: Will this work okay? Sorry, Im still a new here.

Comment: I tested your code and it is working. What error do you get?

Comment: Its not an error, im looking for help on taking the data postedin process.php and submit that to another page that will recommend some products and services. I just dont know where to go from here. I think i understand post and get. But the next step is new to me.

Comment: Ps the products are based off the answers givin in process.php. thanks for looking.

Comment: You can store your data in a file, insert it in a database or may be you want to navigate the user to another page and send the POST data with him. Which one do you want ?

Comment: What wld u think is best...probably to a db wld be good then i cld keep some info from the event, probably for a newbi i should start with sending the post data with him. Using that data depending on the answers ill give them some oter text eplaining products and services.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should store this data into the session and navigate to the products page. On the products page you can retrieve this data easily from the session.

Here is how to store data into the session

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["name"] = $_POST["name"];
$_SESSION["timeFrame"] = $_POST["timeframe"];
$_SESSION["Programs"] = $_POST["Programs"];
```

Then navigate to the products page :

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

To retrieve the data on the products page :

```
$name      = $_SESSION["name"]      
$timeframe = $_SESSION["timeFrame"]
$Programs  = $_SESSION["Programs"]
```

This way your data will be kept untill the user leaves your site. I would suggest to store the data in a database for more practical example.

For more info about sessions :
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

For more info about header function :
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

EDIT: After seeing your updated code. You seem to have a good start in database programming. I advice you to take your time and create a solid base to build on. As of your code I have two notes :

1. Your SQL queries could all be made in one query like this

   ```
     INSERT INTO mortgage (name, email, timeframe, programs) VALUES (.....)
   ```
2. You are using old deprecated functions (Meaning: not supported and not advised to be used). This includes all your `mysql_*` functions. To make the right start you should start using `mysqli_*` for example the connection should be :

   ```
     $con = mysqli_connect(host,username,password,dbname);
   ```

And there will be a few modifications to the rest of your code

I advise you to follow PHP MySQL tutorial at : http://www.w3schools.com/Php/php_mysql_intro.asp
It is very simple and very straight forward and it will be a good start
. Also there is something called SQL injection you should be aware of when you are developing for production. But don't worry about it for now.

As of your question of how to get this data from DB. You will just create simple "SELECT .." and it will get all the data you need. If you follow w3schools tutorial you will find explaination of all of the steps you need to take

Thank you for your complement :). Find good resources on the internet and take your time and make great work.

Comment: I think that wldd work. Thankyou so much. This is sooo helpful. Your a rockstar!

Comment: Now that I have thought about it, I think your right about keeping this information in a database. Here is my post data code: